Error in M language while Calculating Fiscal Quarter
Errors: Expected to find a right parenthesis <')'>, but a keyword <'then'> was found instead
Power Query Editor
I'm trying to find a solution for inserting a new column in Power Query using M Language that calculates the Fiscal Quarter. I'm using Devin Knight's M function "InsertQuarter" to calculate the Fiscal Quarter based on a data table, FYStartMonth, and fiscal year start month. The new column will be called "QuarterOfYear". Here's the function code:
InsertQuarter = Table.AddColumn(InsertMonth, "FiscalQuarter",
      each if([MonthOfYear] >= FYStartMonth then
                (Int([MonthOfYear]) - FYStartMonth + 1) / 3 + 1
            else
               4
         )),

The desired outcome is to have the "FiscalQuarter" column added to the InsertMonth table that shows the fiscal quarters based on the specified start fiscal month and conditions.

I think all you need is: InsertQuarter = Table.AddColumn(InsertMonth, "FiscalQuarter",       each if [MonthOfYear] >= FYStartMonth then (Int([MonthOfYear]) - FYStartMonth + 1) div 3 + 1 else 4),

Just noticed - what is div?

Why not just use Date.QuarterOfYear(#date())

Thank you Rory for commenting but it didn't work. Div = /

In M language, when we use if function, we don't add bracket. That's different from what we do in Excel.
official document

I've tried the other way as well using the regular logic
InsertFYQuarter = Table.AddColumn(InsertQuarternYear, "FY Quarter", each "Q" & Number.ToText(Int32.From(((Date.Month([Date])-FYStartMonth+12)/3)+1)))
I was able to solve a part of the problem but after Q4 it starts as Q5 ,Q6, ....

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Go to power Query, add a blank query, go to advanced editor and paste this code[https://github.com/Ben-alyst/MCode/tree/main], then there will be 3 input fields "StartDate", "EndDate", "FYStartMonth", as per the input the query generates a list of dates and other columns from start date to end date

it has nothing to do with dataset. It is just like calender function in Dax
